# How to know the Server path in which the python file is running?

Tags: python, flask

I am following this online tutorial to learn Flask with MongoDB. I ran my Flask file in my local machine. with the following command

```
python connect.py
```

I don't see any error.

And I wish to see in which path this python file is running. For example, as per the tutorial, the output in the command line shows the following:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

And in my case, I don't see any such server path which I can go and see, for further development.

Can anyone please let me know how I can get to see this path in my machine?

Comment: Maybe you should post the code of connect.py. What does it do?

Comment: If it's not printing automatically, I have a feeling your server isn't running at all.  Are you sure `app.run()` is getting called?

Comment: Youa re right. I had a spelling error in these lines if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True) Thanks. Now it works per the tutorial.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `connect.py`, the directory of this file acts as the root of the website. anything after `/` will be in the same folder as `connect.py`. When you run it, it will create a new socket which, by default, you can access by going to your browser and navigating to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ this can be changed by putting a HOST and or PORT argument inside of where the app is started, usually in app.run() as most tutorials will use as an example, like so.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="192.168.1.11", port=8080, debug=True)
```

http://192.168.1.11:8080/

Comment: Thanks much for your detailed explanation.